# Printing to terminal while piping

Tags: pipe

```
% ping -c 3 stackexchange.com | rev >/tmp/rping
```

saves the result of pinging and reversing.  I would like to do
this while at the same time printing the unreversed output of
`ping` to the terminal.  I would like to do this in real time,
not all at once after `ping` is finished.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Using tee:

```
ping -c 3 stackexchange.com | tee /dev/tty | rev >/tmp/rping
```

Comment: thanks!  somehow i had convinced myself that this would be delayed.

Answer (score 4):

Let `tee` duplicate the output from `ping` to `rev` using a process substitution (assuming you are using a shell that supports these) and to the terminal:

```
$ ping -c 3 stackexchange.com | tee >(rev >/tmp/rping)
ping: Warning: stackexchange.com has multiple addresses; using 151.101.65.69
PING stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=18.887 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=18.514 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=18.508 ms

--- stackexchange.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 18.508/18.636/18.887/0.177 ms
```

There will be no delays in the output of the above text from `ping`.

```
$ cat /tmp/rping
setyb atad 65 :)96.56.101.151( moc.egnahcxekcats GNIP
sm 788.81=emit 25=ltt 0=qes_pmci :96.56.101.151 morf setyb 46
sm 415.81=emit 25=ltt 1=qes_pmci :96.56.101.151 morf setyb 46
sm 805.81=emit 25=ltt 2=qes_pmci :96.56.101.151 morf setyb 46

--- scitsitats gnip moc.egnahcxekcats ---
ssol tekcap %0.0 ,deviecer stekcap 3 ,dettimsnart stekcap 3
sm 771.0/788.81/636.81/805.81 = ved-dts/xam/gva/nim pirt-dnuor
```